# Is it possible to have a non-all-ones broadcast address?

Tags: networking, ip

We've been developing some scripts recently for auto-setting IP address details on our embedded devices.

The method involved setting both the IP address details (e.g., `192.0.0.100/24` and the broadcast address `192.0.0.255`, based on configuration data available to the device at boot time.

Now the reason why we allowed an arbitrary broadcast address is because the Linux `ip` command allows you to set this independently, such as with:

```
ip address add 192.0.0.100/24 dev eth0 broadcast 192.0.0.200
```

However, a colleague thought (and this appears to be borne out by [the relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address)) that there was no discretion allowed, and that the broadcast address for `192.0.0.x` was *required* to be `192.0.0.255` (i.e., all one bits following the  netmask area).

So two questions really:

1. *Is* it required that the broadcast address follow the "all ones" rule?
2. If so, why am I allowed to set an arbitrary broadcast address with the `ip` command?

Answer (score 0):

1) Yep, broadcast address targets all hosts in broadcast domain. If you would like to address only subset of hosts, see multicast.

2) You can set up different broadcast address but it doesn't mean you should do it. It is again standards and it could fails on many devices in network. `ip` command is just a tool, you have to know what you're doing.